# Webpack hangs on build for vue.common.js

Tags: laravel, build, webpack, vue.js

I've installed a fresh laravel app on my VPS and am trying to build it, but it hangs whenever webpack tries to build `node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js`.

Here's the output in the terminal (project name omitted):

```
root@driima:/var/www/html/PROJECT# npm run dev

> @ dev /var/www/html/PROJECT
> node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules

 10% building modules 8/9 modules 1 active ...T/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js
```

And my package.json file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules",
    "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules",
    "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot",
    "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.6.1",
    "vue": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

Could it be a file permissions issue? And if so, what should they be?

EDIT:

I have a file `resources/assets/js/app.js` which calls `import './bootstrap';`, and inside bootstrap.js is the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

window.Vue = Vue;
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

It appears to be hanging when importing Vue, as when I skip importing my bootstrap file, everything compiles successfully.

Comment: What are you trying to do there?

Comment: ...compile everything in my app down? What else?

Comment: You can use strace to trace the problem

Comment: strace hangs at the same line, and prints this, which just keeps looping forever: `epoll_wait(5, {}, 1024, 50) = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and update your deps. This was an issue caused by a minor patch from one of our webpack deps `acorn`. Since yesterday they have published a new patch fixing the issue.

Here's relevant issue: [Webpack 2 hangs on all projects after update](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4184)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a bunch. It honestly didn't occur to me to check webpack's issue tracker. Trust me to decide to install when things are topsy turvy. :)